# Is it possible to remove a disk encryption?

Tags: windows, encryption, disk-encryption, veracrypt, decryption

I have a question about disk encryption. I've read that the best tool to encrypt a whole disk on an existing Windows installation is VeraCrypt. I'm doing it for security and privacy reasons. But before starting an encryption process I'd like to be sure.

Is it possible to remove a disk encryption? Rollback at a time where the disk wasn't encrypted.

---

Running OS : Windows 10
Disks : 1 SSD with Windows, 3 HDD used to store multimedia files
Current state : non encrypted

Comment: It is indeed possible to decrypt your drive after its encrypted with VeraCrypt.  If your only using Windows you should use BitLocker instead

Answer (score 3):

FDE, Full Disk Encryption, is not removed by roll-back. It is removed by decrypting the disk and deactivating the encryption tool or system.

It is a standard process and well documented.

The decryption process can take some time, as it reads all data for the entire disk, decrypts it, and then re-writes it to the disk in an unencrypted form.

Veracrypt's documentation contains instructions on this process: https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Removing%20Encryption.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can remove the encryption on a VeryCrypt volume.  The steps will depend on if the disk is device or partition hosted.  You can read the steps in VeraCrypt's documentation [here](https://documentation.help/VeraCrypt/Removing%20Encryption.html).

Comment: The link implicitly says there's no "rollback" possible. *"Before you continue, make sure you have selected the correct device, as all files stored on it will be lost"*