# Temporarily Turn-Off VeraCrypt

Tags: encryption, veracrypt

I have a laptop that is fully encrypted with VeraCrypt.  I mostly use it at home and do not need encryption.  Is it possible to turn off Veracrypt/not require the Veracrypt password on each reboot temporarily and turn it back on when I take the laptop out?

Comment: FDE cannot just be disable without fully decrypting the drive.

Comment: BitLocker at least has a feature like this, it is called “Suspend Protection”. Maybe VeraCrypt offers something similar.

Comment: @DanielB Spoiler alert: It doesn't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to remove a disk encryption?](https://superuser.com/questions/1613662/is-it-possible-to-remove-a-disk-encryption) Please note the link in the answer that suggests you can: *Before you continue, make sure you have selected the correct device, as **all files stored on it will be lost*** (my bold).

Comment: Make a full disk image before removing encryption -- sometimes things *do* go wrong. Also, you might consider encrypting just a folder, such as Documents, after encryption is removed from the whole disk.